# IncompatibleClassChangeError при роботе с FirebaseInvite

Tags: java, android, firebase

Ловлю вот такую ошибку:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
```

Когда пытаюсь выполнить этот код:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.exaple"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile project(':common')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    //GOOGLE SERVICES
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.0'
    //FACEBOOK
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    //FireBase dependency
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась быстро, изменением версий подключаемых библиотек!

с версий:

```
//GOOGLE SERVICES
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.0'

//FireBase dependency
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
```

заменил но последние версии:

```
//GOOGLE SERVICES
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.4.0'

//FireBase dependency
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
```